# Why is match returning the whole string as the first element in the array?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Let's say I have this string:

`'1234*321*123'`

And I want to get each group of digits as an element in an array.

So I used this:

```
'1234*321*123'.match(/^(\d{4})\*(\d{3})\*(\d{3})$/);
```

But that's returning `["1234*321*123", "1234", "321", "123"]`, when I was expecting `["1234", "321", "123"]`.

**Why, if only the digit groups are enclosed within capturing groups, does `match` return the whole string as the first element of the array?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zeroth element is always the full match. First element is the first capture, second element is the second capture, etc. If you just want all the captures without the full match, you can use `result.slice(1)`.

If you are asking *"Why is the first element the full match?"*:

- It's just the way `match` works.
- It parallels `$0` vs. `$1`, `$2`... in older languages.

Comment: +1 it's an old convention, but it still has use: it makes `match` objects easier to debug, more informative when printed

Answer (score 0):

When you use `()` for matching, it gives both the specific components and the full string. For your desired result, use this:

```
'1234*321*123'.match(/\d+/g);
```

Comment: It has everything to do with `()`. Your comment implies that `'1234*321*123'.match(/\d+/);` would still return the full string as part of the match, and it does not. Using the global flag is just a way to get the desired output.

Comment: `.match(/\d+/)` *does* return the full match (I never said "full string", but "full match"). It does not return anything else. (Accidentally deleted my previous comment, where I claim this has nothing to do with `()`, but with `//g`, where `.match` does not give captures, only full matches)

Comment: Where are you running it to produce that? Chrome console gives `["1234"]` for `'1234*321*123'.match(/\d+/)`. Edit: OK I think we're talking about the same thing / picking at straws

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly what it is: the full match of `/\d+/`. If you were to take `/(\d+)/`, you would get `["1234", "1234"]`: the full match (not the "full string"!) and the first capture (in this case being the same string).